# Correct way to format custom Python Logging Class

Tags: python, logging

I am looking to integrate a request ID with all my Flask Logs using https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Log-Request-ID/

currently in my app.ini for Flask app I have

```
[formatter_generic]
level = debug
datefmt = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z
class = logging.LogFormatter
qualname = fa4ns
```

```
import logging
from flask_log_request_id import current_request_id


class LogFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    
    def format(self, record):
       
        return f"ll={record.__dict__.get('levelname')} " \
               f"rid={current_request_id()} " \
               f"lno={record.__dict__.get('lineno')} "
```

However, I'm not a fan of accessing the log record dict directly to extra values. Is there a cleaner way so I can access values similar to

```
logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s%(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S%p')
```

Comment: The appropriate replacement for `obj.__dict__` is `vars(obj)` and for the whole `obj.__dict__.get('attribute')` it's `getattr(obj, 'attribute')`.